# Is there a purely command line tool to generate call hierarchies for c++?

Tags: linux, software-development, c++, command-line

I'm looking for something like [cflow](http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/cflow.html#Intro) but for C++.

`ctags` helps us find the definition. I want to find the callers, which is the reverse problem.

Comment: I don't have an answer (and I did not know about cflow actually), but - it seems that tools like exuberant ctags and the IDE provisioning of invocation-to-definition in C++ are somewhat similar in functionality to what you're asking for.

Comment: @einpoklum, `ctags` helps us find the definition. I want to find the callers, which is the reverse problem.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. What are your requirements? How much money are you willing to spend (or must it be free)?

Answer (score 1):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), *which can be invoked from the command line once you have produced a doxyfile*, can produce [caller graph](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_caller_graph) for all, or [selected](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcallergraph), functions/methods, in a given code project but these are normally viewed in a browser. You will also need the GraphViz DOT tool.

- Free
- Cross Platform
- C++ and several other languages

Comment: How does Doxygen handle indirect function pointers, or virtual methods?

Comment: @IraBaxter - I am reasonably sure that Doxygen will handle virtual methods. It also should pick up simple uses of function pointers, e.g. if you have a lookup table of functions to call depending on the current state I would expect it to work but if you are passing function/class pointers around and then calling them from elsewhere I would expect you to be out of luck. _I would also hope that you would be looking to refactor._